# Pandas Conditionally Concatenate

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string-concatenation

Given the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['[a]','[b'],
                   'bar':['[a','[b]']})
df
    bar  foo
0   [a]  [a
1   [b   [b]
```

I want to add a closing bracket "]" to those cells where the values lack them.
The desired result is:

```
    bar  foo
0   [a]  [a]
1   [b]  [b]
```

However, I am unsure how many columns I will have so I'd like to apply it to the whole data frame.

I started out with this, but had no luck:

```
df2 = df(lambda x: str(x)+"]" if (len(x)<3))
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:
I'm actually working with a table that looks like this:

```
    0       1        2 
0   b [r]   None    None
1   c [d    d [r]   f[d]
2   g [r]   h [d]   None
3   m [r    p [d]   None
4   b [r]   n [d
5   m [d]   a [r]   None
```

Comment: Thanks for the great responses. I notice that when some cells contain "None" or are blank, I get the following error: IndexError: string index out of range. I should have shown that table in the original question, but I didn't think it would matter. I'll post it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use loop by columns, because `string` function works with `Series`. Use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html)

```
print df
   bar  foo
0   [a  [a]
1  [b]   [b

for cols in df.columns:
    #print df[cols].str[-1] != ']'  
    df.loc[df[cols].str[-1] != ']', cols] = df[cols] + ']'
print df   
   bar  foo
0  [a]  [a]
1  [b]  [b]
```

Or use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with inverted mask by `~`:

```
for cols in df.columns:
    df.loc[~df[cols].str[-1].str.contains(']'), cols] = df[cols] + ']'
print df   
   bar  foo
0  [a]  [a]
1  [b]  [b]
```

Thank you for comment of [root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017405/pandas-conditionally-concatenate/36017594?noredirect=1#comment59686941_36017594) use [`endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
for cols in df.columns:
    df.loc[~df[cols].str.endswith(']'), cols] = df[cols] + ']'
print df
```

EDIT:

If there are empty `strings` and `none` values:

```
print df
0   [a      
1  [b]    [b
2   [a  None

for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[~df[col].str.endswith(']').replace({np.nan: False}), col] = df[col] + ']'
    df[col] = df[col].replace({']': ''})

print df   
   bar  foo
0  [a]     
1  [b]  [b]
2  [a]  NaN
```

Comment: I think using `endswith` may be simpler than `contains`.  E.g. `~df[cols].str.endswith(']')`

Comment: Sorry, I should have put the comment here; what if there is a blank cell? That seems to be giving me an index error: string index out of range. I tried this but no dice:     df2.loc[(~df2[cols].str[-1].str.endswith(']'))&(~pd.isnull[cols]), cols] = df2[cols] + ']'

Comment: If there is empty `string`, can be in output `NaN` ?

Comment: For `endswith` you don't need the `.str[-1]` component, as it is implied (that's the whole point of `endswith`).  Just `~df[cols].str.endswith(']')` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Let's learn about the `DataFrame.applymap()` function

```
df.applymap(func_reference)
```

The line above will call the `func_reference` on each cell in `df`. Now we can design our `func_reference`.

```
def my_filter(cell):
    if cell[-1] == ']':
        return cell
    return cell + ']'

filtered_df = df.applymap(my_filter)
```

This may not be the most efficient way, but I think it is quite readable.